# What is going on with FIDE's latest rapid and blitz ratings? Some players are more than 500 points higher in one month!

Tags: fide, rating, blitz, rapid

It's the last day of September and the provisional rating list for October has been released. There are some very strange ratings changes in that ratings list. [Sri Lankan IM LMST De Silva](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/9953698/chart) played no FIDE rated rapid or blitz games in September but his rapid rating has risen from 1751 to 2416. Similarly his blitz rating has risen from 1727 to 2416.

What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Checking the latest [FIDE Handbook](https://handbook.fide.com/), there is a new section, [FIDE Rapid and Blitz Rating Regulations effective from 1 October 2022](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B02RBRegulations202210). However this is virtually identical to the previous section, [FIDE Rapid and Blitz Rating Regulations effective from 1 January 2022 till 30 September 2022](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B02RBRegulations2022).

It seems there is a [newer version](https://doc.fide.com/docs/DOC/2FC2022/CM2_2022_29.pdf) still of the rating regulations for rapid and blitz which hasn't quite managed to get properly linked from the main documents.

This says:

> **1. Rapid & Blitz**
>
> It was submitted a proposal to the Management Board 11/07/2022 to consider:
>
> - **A one-off rating change to Rapid and Blitz**
>   In the rating list published on 1st October, 2022, there will be a one-off change to the rapid and blitz ratings of players who have them:
> - If the player is unrated in rapid or blitz, then they remain unrated in rapid or blitz
> - If the standard rating is more than 100 points higher than one of the other ratings, then that rating is moved up to: standard rating minus 100 points
> - If the standard rating is 100 or less points higher than one of the ratings, then
>   the player retains their rating

IM LMST De Silva's rapid and blitz ratings were a lot more than 100 points lower than his standard rating and so have been moved up to be 100 points less than his standard rating.